# Can't get Spring WebClient to work Flux, DataBuffers, Error Handling, and Headers

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm trying to get the Spring WebClient to work with making a GET request for downloading potentially large files, where the filename is in a Content-Disposition header. This worked fine for smaller files and didn't want to increase memory usage and continue to use Monos. Spent a bit trying to get it to work with Flux but i can't.

```java
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
Flux<?> response =
        webClient.get()
                .uri( builder -> builder.path( PATH )
                                            .build() )
                .exchangeToFlux( clientResponse -> {
                    if ( !clientResponse.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful() )
                        return Flux.from( clientResponse.createException() );
                    httpHeaders.putAll( clientResponse.headers().asHttpHeaders() );
                    return clientResponse.bodyToFlux( DataBuffer.class );
                } );
File f = File.createTempFile( "file-", "bin" );
try ( FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( f ) ) {
    DataBufferUtils.write( (Flux<DataBuffer>) response, fos );
    File f2 = new File( f.getParentFile(),
            httpHeaders.getContentDisposition().getFilename() );
    f.renameTo( f2 );
    return f2;
}
```

That's is the closest i could get, but the DataBufferUtils write method throws a ClassCastException on error and i didn't want to go creating my own copy of it to get it to work. I wanted it to continue to throw WebClientExceptions if something went wrong like it did when I was parsing the body to a Mono.

Comment: why the `Flux<?>`? maybe you should figure out what the actual type is, before trying to cast something into something it isnt. Also saying that something just throws a `ClassCastException` isn't a proper error description, the error and the stacktrace are actually information we programmers need to solve problems. They are not only there to take up space.